# SQL Count Value if the data is lower then current date

Tags: date

I want to verify the compliance by month. I already have the below query.
Only add the moment I am getting the following information

[image]

Only I would like to retrieve the following information add the total number if the month is lower as the date value as below. What should I modify in my query.

[image]

```
SELECT Account
      , ACompliant = CASE WHEN Account = 'No' THEN '1' END
      , ANonCompliant = CASE WHEN Account = 'Yes' THEN '1' END
      , ATotal = CASE WHEN ResourceID is not null THEN '1' END
      , Date = FORMAT("Date",'yyyyMM')
      ,[Excluded]
  INTO #temptest
  FROM [Stats].[dbo].[Accounts]

  SELECT Compliant = COUNT(ACompliant)
  ,NonCompliant=COUNT(ANonCompliant)
  ,Total=COUNT(ATotal)
  , Date
  FROM #temptest
  GROUP BY Date

  DROP TABLE #temptest
```

Comment: Please provide scripts for creating tables and data. And please don't use images for data. And what is the database engine you are using.

Comment: If you have answered your own question, you should add the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a windowed `SUM` or `COUNT` to get a running total.

It seems you want to aggregate first, so you can do a window function over an aggregation function `SUM(COUNT(...)) OVER ...`

```sql
SELECT ACompliant    = SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN a.Account = 'No' THEN 1 END))
            OVER (ORDER BY a.Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
     , ANonCompliant = SUM((CASE WHEN a.Account = 'Yes' THEN 1 END))
            OVER (ORDER BY a.Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
     , ATotal        = SUM(COUNT(a.ResourceID))
            OVER (ORDER BY a.Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
     , Date = FORMAT(a.Date, 'yyyyMM')
FROM dbo.Accounts a
GROUP BY
  a.Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>*Self answer originally left in the question body*</sub>

This fixed it now:

```
SELECT a.Account
     , ACompliant    = SUM(CAST(v.ACompliant as int)) OVER (ORDER BY a.Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
     , ANonCompliant = SUM(CAST(v.ANonCompliant as int)) OVER (ORDER BY a.Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
     , ATotal        = SUM(CAST(v.ATotal as int))        OVER (ORDER BY a.Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
     , Date = FORMAT(a.Date, 'yyyyMM')
     into #temp3
FROM [Stats].[dbo].[Accounts] a
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      ACompliant = CASE WHEN a.Account = 'No' THEN '1' END
    , ANonCompliant = CASE WHEN a.Account

    = 'Yes' THEN '1' END
    , ATotal = CASE WHEN a.ResourceID is not null THEN '1' END
) v;

select Compliant = MAX(ACompliant)
,NonCompliant = MAX(ANonCompliant)
,Total = max(ATotal)
,Date
from #temp3
group by Date

drop table #temp3
```